# Is it possible to modify a Python programs AST?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

Would it be possible to parse in the AST of a Python Program, then modify it, and then execute it? To be specific, I want to alter the behaviour of string literals. Instead of wrapping each string in a function call, I thought I may be able to modify the AST.

```
BUILDDIR = macro('build')
SOURCES = macro('$wildcard(src/*.cpp)')
```

would become

```
BUILDDIR = 'build'
SOURCES = '$wildcard(src/*.cpp)'
```

Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard library `ast` module to do the first part. You'll probably need to use [NodeTransformer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.NodeTransformer).

You can then use the [codegen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/codegen/1.0) module to create source code, which you could then execute.

Proof of concept:

```
import ast
import codegen
expr = """
BUILDDIR = 'build'
"""
p = ast.parse(expr)
# your code here...
exec(codegen.to_source(p))
```